# how to get locale from context onConversationUpdate on ms teams chat BotBuilder

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

**onConversationUpdate** is not returning **locale** as of now... is it possible to get locale when welcome message trigger from bot section ?

[image: Activity object is not having locale info]

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You will get locale information only when user initiate/invoke some action. Like sending message or interacting with the bot.